# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un multi color linear-gradient en un solo estilo?

Tags: css3

Tengo el siguiente color de fondo pero tengo que ir escalando entre el `body`
-> `<div class="background">` y `<div class="container">` para obtener este resultado:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300';

html, body, .background
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 background: white;
}

body
{
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 200, 0) );
}

.background
{
 background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(50, 150, 100, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 100, 0) );
}

.container
{
 background: linear-gradient(240deg, rgba(150, 50, 50, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 200, 0) );
 
    display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

h1
{
 color: white;
 font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>hello</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Cómo puedo obtener ese mismo color de fondo en una solo estilo es decir tener ese fondo en un solo contenedor, en un solo `div` u otro sin que tenga que agregar a otros elementos para poder obtener el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que buscas algo como esto:

```css
.rainbow {
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 200, 0)), 
  linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(50, 150, 100, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 100, 0) ),
   linear-gradient(240deg, rgba(150, 50, 50, 0.6) , rgba(0, 0, 200, 0) );
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class='rainbow'> 
    <p >Hello</p>
 </div>
```

Espero haberte apoyado. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que necesitaba :)